# Flutter check if the value of a particular field is true or false

Tags: firebase, flutter

Am trying to check the auth status of users in my firestore db but am unable to implement the conditional logic.
Certain users are granted admin status and I want to check if is admin or not.

Here is a function am trying to use

```
checkfirebase(var userid)async{

   await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(userid)

        .get()
        .then((adminstatus) {
      if (adminstatus.data("isadmin")==true) {
        // return true;
      } else {
        // return false;
      }
```

The above code returns `error: Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.` which is coming from this line `adminstatus.data("isadmin")==true`

Is there a way to check if user is admin or not?

Comment: what is `adminstatus`?

Answer (score 0):

Update your code to this -

```
var userDocument = adminstatus.data();
if(userDocument['isAdmin']==true)
{
//return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.data()`returns an object (or map) of the snapshot and you need to access the required property from that.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('users')
  .doc(userid)
  .get()
  .then((adminstatus) {
    if (adminstatus.data()["isadmin"]==true) {
      // return true;
    } else {
      // return false;
    }
  })
```